# How to redirect with 301 in Next.js middleware?

Tags: next.js

I know I can set `permanent` or status code in `next.config.js` and in `getServerSideProps`.

But I can't find a way to set redirect status code in `middleware.js`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
```

write your middleware

```
export async function middleware(req, ev) {
    // you wrote your logic
 
    return NextResponse.redirect("/login",301)
}
```

I did not test this but looked at NextResponse class:

```
export declare class NextResponse extends Response {
    [INTERNALS]: {
        cookieParser(): {
            [key: string]: string;
        };
        url?: NextURL;
    };
    constructor(body?: BodyInit | null, init?: ResponseInit);
    get cookies(): {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    cookie(name: string, value: {
        [key: string]: any;
    } | string, opts?: CookieSerializeOptions): this;
    clearCookie(name: string, opts?: CookieSerializeOptions): this;
    static json(body: any): NextResponse;
    static redirect(url: string | NextURL | URL, status?: number): NextResponse;
    static rewrite(destination: string | NextURL): NextResponse;
    static next(): NextResponse;
}
```

this is the `redirect` method

```
 static redirect(url: string | NextURL | URL, status?: number)
```